# Saving CSV-UTF8 to a existing file path?

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code by Raymond, but it saves into MyDocuments, how could I change this piece of code to an existing file path on my computer?

```
Sub SaveWorkSheetAsCSV()

Dim wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim name As String



    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    name = "test"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
    wbNew.SaveAs name & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8 'new way
    wbNew.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim myPath As String` `myPath = "C:\myfolder"` and then `wbNew.SaveAs myPath & "\" & name & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8`

Comment: How should I put this in the code? Replace wbNew.SaveAs name & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8 'new way with wbNew.SaveAs myPath & "\" & name & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8 ? And where should I put Dim myPath As String myPath = "C:\myfolder" ?

Comment: You may put the declaration wherever you want, but the nicer way should be to add it near the existing declarations. Anyhow,  I will post an answer with the updated code. But I think you must learn such simple VBA issues. You cannot only take code and not understand how it is built and how it works...

Comment: You got a point there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try your modified code:

```
Sub SaveWorkSheetAsCSV()
 Dim wbNew As Excel.Workbook
 Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim name As String, myPath As String

    myPath = "C:\myfolder" 'use here the path you need
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    name = "test"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
    wbNew.SaveAs myPath & "\" & name & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8  'new way
    wbNew.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ultimate Processor: Didn't you find some time to test the adapted code? if tested, some feedback did not kill anybody...

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to test it now!